# related to resizing iframe according to contentsize

Tags: iframe

hi with respect to the given solution of the question

```
function resizeIframe(obj) { { obj.style.height = 0; } ; 
 { obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'; } }
```

its working fine in firefox but to make it work also in chrome what should be done ?

and one more thing on my website when the required page of services will be loaded I want there will be a little introduction about service section is visible in iframe and then I have left bar in which there are links of services and when I click the link then only the content related to that service should be loaded and visible in iframe and the iframe should resize its size according to the size of content, otherwise just the introduction should remain there.

how can i do this ? please tell the code